# Pathing with setup.py entry_points

Tags: python, path, package, setup.py

Wasn't really sure how to grab this problem of mine but.. I'm a beginner with packaging and setup.py. I have a script in a directory.

Directory:

```
-root-
--setup.py (setup file in root dir)

-srcdir (dir with src code)
  --script.py (script in srcdir - WITH function main())

-confdir (dir with conf file)
  --config.conf (config itself)
```

I installed it with `python setup.py bdist_wheel` and then `pip install -e .` from root directory where the setup.py file is. My setup.py file contains an entry point `entry_points={"console_scripts": {"fish=script:main"}}` (it means that I can call `fish` from anywhere with cmd and it runs the main() function in script.py file).

Now I have a question. From the script.py file - I'm reading config.conf. If I call `fish` from any directory I'm not able to access the config file bcs I'm using relative path in the script.py. Is there a way of accessing it without using the absolute pathing?

Baically I need relative pathing from the script I'm running and not the directory I'm in with cmd. Is there a way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the config file was another Python module, you could simply import it:

```py
from ..confdir import config
```

However since it seems to be some other kind of file, you can use the `__file__` variable to create a path relative to `script.py`:

```py
from pathlib import Path

conf_path = Path(__file__).parents[1] / 'confdir' / 'config.conf'
```

And don't forget to include `config.conf` in your [`MANIFEST.in`](https://packaging.python.org/guides/using-manifest-in/) (+ use [`include_package_data=True`](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/non-code-files.html) in `setup.py`).

Comment: It was actually `conf_path = os.path.join(__file__, '../../confdir/config.conf')` bcs the last item in `__file__` is the file itself and you need to "back" from it. But thank you, really helped me to understand!